# why is googling the definition of "aviance" so difficult?

Tags: vocabulary

I was just checking on the spelling of "aviance". However, google is giving me very surprising results. Please type "aviance", "aviance definition", and "what does aviance mean" into the google search engine to see what I mean.

The "aviance of a restaurant" is pretty common phrase to say. "Aviance" sounds French, so I could understand why English dictionaries do not have a definition for it. But, a broad google search turns-up nothing regarding "aviance" meaning "atmosphere". I mean, "aviance" is not that simple of a word, so I would have expected that non-native speakers would have asked tons of questions about its meaning, and usage. But, there is nothing. What is going on?

Comment: I think you mean *ambiance*. There isn't any English word *aviance*.

Comment: You have done a good job explaining the situation. This question appears to be off-topic because it is about misremembering a word.

Comment: But, I know I've heard the phrase "the aviance of the restaurant was nice". That basically means "the atmosphere of the restaurant was nice." right? I don't know what to say.

Comment: Maybe that person was pronouncing it incorrectly, or maybe you misheard, or maybe you misremembered, but everything you describe suggests that you are looking for *ambiance*.

Comment: @user312440 Without evidence, your statement of knowledge is unsubstantiable conjecture subject to perceptual whims and miscues.

Comment: Despite it obviously being based on a mistake, I don't think this question is off-topic: as Xrylite said (and I've confirmed), none of the usual suspect reference sources will tell you that what you're hearing as "aviance" is actually spelled (and said, but whatever) "ambiance".

Comment: @Marthaª That's true, but this question is unlikely to help future visitors. If it were broadened into something like "is this a commonly confused phonetic pair", we could leave it open. As it is, I think the user has a helpful answer.

Comment: (Please don't delete the contents of your question - just because it's closed doesn't mean it's a bad question. It just means that it's unnecessary for it to sit around collecting new answers.)

Comment: @Marthaª sorry. I did not understand that protocol. thank you.

Comment: Allow me to just register a spot of raised eyebrows at the fact that every single instance of the word on this page—in both comments and answers—has used the much less common spelling _ambiance_, as opposed to the more common _ambience_. Colour me surprised!

Comment: wouldn't *aviance* be the proportion of birds in a location?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, my browser marks "ambience" as misspelled, but doesn't even sneeze at "ambiance". I think this might be a US vs. Britain difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have more success trying to google [**ambiance**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambience).

Comment: Why would I google "ambiance"? I am asking about the word "aviance".

Comment: @user312440, you should try looking up *ambiance* rather than *aviance* because the former is a word, while the latter is not.

Comment: ok. I am an auditory learner. And, I am almost certain I've heard a phrase that, when written phonetically, sounds like "the aviance of the restaurant". But, obviously I am wrong.

Comment: @KitFox; Actually the word is *ambience*, as the link shows; you appear to have misled every other commenter into believing in the nonexistent word **ambiance*. This was clearly a postmodern comment on those who misremember the misremembering of a word rather than inadvertence; my congratulations on your subtlety.

Comment: YES! That is the word I was thinking about. "ambiance" / "ambience". Exactly. Thank you so much! I can rest now. thank you.

Comment: @Tim That is extremely funny. I changed the spelling on that thrice and still got it wrong. It's the French spelling; I'm sure that's why it got me.

Comment: @Tim [_Ambiance_ is also allowed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ambience) by most dictionaries (see “also _ambiance_” right under the header, and the “Variants of _ambience_” section in the M-W link). Not pretty, but an accepted variant.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Beauty is in the eye of the beholder... I personally find the French styled spelling quite pretty :)

Comment: @KitFox, as I noted above, my browser thinks that "ambiance" is the correct spelling, and it marks "ambience" as misspelled. My experience agrees with this: "ambiance" looks correct to me, and "ambience" looks slightly... off. Every dictionary I've checked so far has listed both spellings; they're about evenly divided on which spelling they consider the "main" one, though there is more than one that has the full definition only under "ambiance", and "ambience" merely has a link to the former entry.

Answer (score 3):

Google has its limitations too on knowing what you mean, especially if you accidentally typo a word into an actual brand. In this case, *ambiance* is the atmospheric feeling that you're referring to.

If you're ever in doubt, you can always try putting the word into a thesaurus or dictionary website to see if it shows up there. Most will go beyond English language. However, in this case, I couldn't pull up any results for the word '*aviance*' which wasn't the brand *Aviance*.

Comment: Just, for the final record, what I had been doing was, when I read the word "ambience", I pronounced it similar to the word "ambient" as in "ambient temperature". In conversation, I was hearing a word that sounded like "aviance" (to me at least). So, I'd thought that there were 2 words. One I knew to spell but used an "ambient" like mispronunciation. The other, I knew how to pronounce, but misspelled it as "aviance". In fact, there really is just one word.

Comment: Very understandable. I suppose my wording was poor by calling it a *typo*, rather than a misunderstanding. It's experiences like these where you may literally never see that word again without thinking back to this moment =). I admit that my spell-check commonly is by using Google, so it was just a strange scenario where it gave you results for what you searched... but not ones you were after~.